# ios seek bar moving to center of player on slow connectivity

Tags: ios, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am playing live streaming content. But the seek bar moves to the centre of the player if it is not in full screen mode. I observed that this is happening when the network connectivity is slow. Does anyone have a solution for this?

I want to notify the user that the network connectivity is slow.

```
self.movieController = [[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
        initWithContentURL: inURL] autorelease];
movieController.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[movieController play];
```

Comment: If you can, try posting captures of your problem, it's sometimes easier than explaining with words :)

Comment: I hope you meant the thumb, not the complete seek bar, screenshot will be welcome.

Comment: @girishpatil : is the issue sorted out?